# Is it possible to run mypy pre-commit without making it fail?

Tags: mypy, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

I would like to add the following to [pre-commit](https://pre-commit.com/) for a team:

```
-   repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-mypy
    rev: 'v0.720'
    hooks:
    -   id: mypy
        args: [--ignore-missing-imports]
```

My team is worried that this might be too strict. To have a gradual introduction, I would like this hook not to make the commit fail, but only to show the issues. Is that possible?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

you can, but I wouldn't suggest it -- warning noise is likely to have your whole team ignore the entire output and the entire tool

here's how you would do such a thing (note that it has reduced portability due to `bash` -- mostly because the framework intentionally does not suggest this)

```
-   repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-mypy
    rev: v0.720
    hooks:
    -   id: mypy
        verbose: true
        entry: bash -c 'mypy "$@" || true' --
```

two pieces make this work:

1. `verbose: true` always produces the output -- this option is really only intended for debugging purposes, but you can turn it on always (it can be noisy / annoying though)
2. `bash` + `|| true` -- ignore the exit code

disclaimer: I am the author of pre-commit

Answer (score 5):

Also note that you can [temporarily disable hooks](https://pre-commit.com/#temporarily-disabling-hooks) by setting the environment variable `SKIP`. For example:

```
SKIP=flake8 git commit -m 'fix thing - work in progress'
```

This is especially useful when you just want to make local "checkpoint" commits that you'll fix later.

**Side note on mypy specifically**: there's a potentially big issue with using mypy in a non-blocking way like this. If you allow commits with type errors to be merged, everyone else will start to see those type errors in their pre-commit checks.

When developers are making further changes, it's confusing whether the mypy errors that appear were there from before, or due to their further changes. This can be a recipe for frustration/confusion, and also for allowing further type errors to accumulate.

I think the mypy guide on [using mypy with an existing codebase](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/existing_code.html) is pretty good advice.

If you just need to temporarily skip mypy checks so you can checkpoint your work, push a PR for initial review, or whatever, you can just do `SKIP=mypy` as mentioned above.